# do log backup on secondary node (sync or async) can truncate transaction log on primary?

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups

i have 4 nodes. 2 nodes in sync mode, 2 nodes in asyn mode. Can i relocate all backup jobs (full, tlog) on any secondary? does the backup truncate the transaction log on primary?

Answer (score 1):

> Can i relocate all backup jobs (full, tlog) on any secondary?

[You can](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/active-secondaries-backup-on-secondary-replicas-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver16), however as of now only `copy_only` full backups are supported on secondary replicas. Also, if the secondary replica is behind, for example an async replica that has a send queue, then it can only back up the portion of the log that it has.

> does the backup truncate the transaction log on primary?

Log backups taken on a secondary replica will allow log truncation on a primary replica if it meets the normal criteria for log truncation.

Comment: And note that if you only take COPY_ONLY full backups, you can't really use differential backups, as the differential base will never be reset.